# Electron auto-updates not working on MacOS if app is not installed in Applications directory

Tags: javascript, electron

I am using the auto-updater module from Electron framework to implement auto updates for my Electron application on MacOS. The updates succeed only if the app is installed in Applications folder. If it is installed somewhere else, the updates do not work. I am using the implementation detailed here- https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5020#issuecomment-477636990. The download succeeds but the app doesn't update on relaunch.

Can someone help me with why this is happening and how to fix this.